# Kafka with KRAFT authentification

Tags: apache-kafka

I have kafka with KRAFT, and i want that my users(in python) only have access to specific topic, which created specially for them.
Please any advices, i totally don't understand how to make it. I can create SSL, but it will protect only from outside, but any user will have possibility to read info from topic of other user. I am planning to use SASL/SCRAM to dynamic add users and SSL.But i can't find how to configure it

here is my config

```
  kafka-0:
image: docker.io/bitnami/kafka:${KAFKA_VERSION}
hostname: kafka-0
container_name: kafka-0
ports:
  - "9094:9094"
environment:
  # KRaft settings
  - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=0
  - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
  - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@kafka-0:9093,1@kafka-1:9093,2@kafka-2:9093
  - KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
  # Listeners
  - KAFKA_CFG_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=20000000
  - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=BROKER://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
  #- KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=BROKER://:9092,EXTERNAL://${HOST_IP}:9094
  - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=BROKER://:9092
  #- KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
  - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=BROKER:SASL_PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:SASL_PLAINTEXT
  - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=BROKER
  - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
  # Clustering
  - KAFKA_CFG_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
  - KAFKA_CFG_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
  - KAFKA_CFG_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR=2
  # Authentification
  - KAFKA_CFG_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS=SCRAM-SHA-256
  - KAFKA_CFG_SASL_MECHANISM_CONTROLLER_PROTOCOL=PLAIN
  - KAFKA_CFG_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=SCRAM-SHA-256
  - KAFKA_LISTENER_NAME_BROKER_SCRAM-SHA-256_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG='org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="admin" password="admin-secret" user_admin="admin-secret"'
  - KAFKA_LISTENER_NAME_BROKER_PLAIN_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG='org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="admin" password="admin-secret" user_admin="admin-secret"'
  - KAFKA_LISTENER_NAME_CONTROLLER_PLAIN_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG='org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="admin" password="admin-secret" user_admin="admin-secret"'
  - KAFKA_LISTENER_NAME_CONTROLLER_SCRAM-SHA-256_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG='org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="admin" password="admin-secret" user_admin="admin-secret"'
  - KAFKA_CLIENT_USERS=admin
  - KAFKA_CLIENT_PASSWORDS=admin-secret
```

but got errors

> "kafka-1          |
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException:
> Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials
> with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-256 "

Comment: The [Authorisation section](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz) of the Kafka docs is a good place to start.

Comment: haha , it's not working. I update question